# Is anyone interested in Rexer Analytics 2015 Data Miner Survey? 5/30

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to post this here? In previous Rexer surveys, Mathematica is not among the top 10 systems used. Likely to change going fwd:

http://www.rexeranalytics.com/Data-Miner-Survey-2015-Intro.html

Since it closes

[image]

> Data Analysts, Predictive Modelers, Data Scientists, Data Miners, and
>   all other types of analytic professionals, students, and academics: 
>   Please participate in the Rexer Analytics 2015 Data Miner Survey. We
>   will be closing the Survey on May 30th, so if you would like to
>   participate, please do so now. If you have already participated, thank
>   you so much for your time.   We ask you to help with two things:
>          1) Answer the survey questions
>          2) Tell other data analysis professionals about the survey (forward this email to them).  Forwarding the survey is invaluable as
>   it helps the survey reach a wide and diverse group.   Thank you!
>   Rexer Analytics has been conducting the Data Miner Survey since 2007. 
>   Each survey explores the analytic behaviors, views and preferences of
>   data miners and analytic professionals.  Over 1200 people from around
>   the globe participated in the 2013 survey.  Summary reports from
>   previous surveys are available FREE to everyone who requests them by
>   emailing us at DataMinerSurvey@RexerAnalytics.com.  Also, highlights
>   of earlier Data Miner Surveys are available online, including best
>   practices shared by respondents on analytic success measurement,
>   overcoming data mining challenges, and other topics.  The FREE Summary
>   Report for this 2015 Data Miner Survey will be available to everyone
>   in the fall of 2015.   Your survey responses are completely
>   confidential.  This research is not being conducted on behalf of any
>   third party, but is solely for Rexer Analytics to disseminate the
>   findings throughout the data mining and analytics community.   To
>   participate, please click on the link below, then click on the “Start
>   Survey” link on the bottom of the webpage.  Please enter the access
>   code in the space provided.  The survey should take approximately
>   15-20 minutes to complete.  Anyone who has had this email forwarded to
>   them should use the access code in the forwarded email.